# Intelij Rider arrow keys moves next word instead of next character

Tags: c#, asp.net, shortcut, rider

A few days ago I was playing around with some keyboard shortcuts and changed something, but have no idea what i changed. Since then, when i press <right-arrow> my caret moves forwards to the end of the next word, instead of to the next character.

I tried looking this up but could not find anything that worked, I can only move my caret to the middle of a word by using my mouse (as a vim keybinds user, this is hell)

Please end my suffering and help me return to normal caret movement

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and the issue was that in the Keybinding settings it had set the hotkey for moving a whole word back 'Ctrl-Left' as well as normal 'Left', and the same for 'Ctrl-Right' and 'Right'. I removed 'Left' and 'Right' from those keybindings and now it works great.

Comment: Nice that you managed to resolve it, mine resolved the next day on its own (gosh what the fuck, I still don't know how that works), so I don't think it was the same issue